# Angular router parameter

Tags: angular, parameters, router

My angular web site has a component which reads the parameter passed in the url

```
www.mywebsite.com/main?id=value
```

Is it possible to make the user type

```
www.mywebsite.com/main/gianni
```

and the component get `gianni` and the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Router setup:

```
{
    path: 'main/:id',
    component: MainComponent
},
```

In your main component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.loadData(id);
    });
  }
```

Working example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eoh3nr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.ts).

**UPDATE**

To pass received value, try this:

main.component.html (pass received id to contact component's "id" @Input property)

```
<app-contact [id]="id"></app-contact>
```

contact.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-contact",
  templateUrl: "./contact.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./contact.component.css"]
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() id;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes["id"]) {
      console.log(`call backend to get data for [${this.id}]`);
    }
  }

}
```

new [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4xkjyl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontact%2Fcontact.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks, now that I can read the "id" how can I pass it to another component? Let me explain, I read the value in the main component and I'd like to pass it to the contact component

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // routes
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: AnotherComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

everything passed by parameter after www.mywebsite.com/main/**gianna** will be available at

> this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

You may want to have a look [here](https://angular.io/guide/router)