# Angular Routing Parameter Routing Incorrectly

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to setup my Angular routing and I do not think that I am doing it correctly. I have the following:

```typescript
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: '/login'
            },
            ... // truncated for brevity
            {
                component: ClientErrorComponent,
                path: 'error'
            },
            {
                path: 'form',
                children: [
                    {
                        component: FormEntriesComponent,
                        path: ':formId',
                        pathMatch: 'full',
                        children: [
                            {
                                component: FormEntryComponent,
                                path: ':id'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        path: '',
                        pathMatch: 'full',
                        redirectTo: '/error?code=400&info=You cannot go to an empty form.'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/error?code=400&info=Uh oh! Something went wrong, you used an invalid URL somehow.'
    }
];
```

What I would like to do is when I go to `localhost:4200/form/1` it goes to the first child child component of `form` and when I go to `localhost:4200/form/1/1` it goes to the first child's child component.

However, every time I try to go to the former it hits `**` redirect.

I thought followed the advice of this thread [Angular router parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292804/angular-router-parameter), but I continue to hit the redirect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's been some time that I didn't touch on the Angular project. But think that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68446477/8017690) may help you.

Comment: Not sure it's work, but try to move the children from `""` up one level, so those children's path are in the same level with `**` (wildcard).

Comment: Could you clarify why localhost:4200/form/1 and localhost:4200/form/1/1 tries to render FormEntryComponent? There seems to either be a typo and what you're really trying to do is to access other component when hitting  localhost:4200/form/:formId/:id that's why you have trouble or you have some modelling issue

Comment: @michal.materowski - Good catch. The former should be hitting FormEntriesComponent. I will update my code.

Comment: @YongShun - I understand what the double asterisk is used for, so unfortunately the linked question didn't help me. I did however, try to move the children up one level with ** defined as the last item, but it is still doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting route match, because you try to implement `pathMatch: full` strategy.

Router cannot find the route which has explicitly path `form/:formId/:id` so it ignores it and hits `"**"` redirect.

Notice that you're getting match for `form/:formId` because  `path: 'form'` has default pathMatch strategy and it is able to access children segment and look for a `:formId` match there.

Remove this segment and make sure **FormEntriesComponent** has `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in it's template.

```
{
    path: 'form',
    children: [
      {
        component: FormEntriesComponent,
        path: ':formId',
        children: [
          {
            component: FormEntryComponent,
            path: ':id',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: So unfortunately when I use this example it always loads the parent (i.e. FormEntriesComponent).

Comment: I made a Stackblitz where I reproduce this behaviour https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-2ccpzg?file=app%2Fapp.routing.module.ts,app%2Fviews%2Fcatalog%2Fcatalog-child.component.ts,app%2Fviews%2Fcatalog%2Fcatalog.component.ts,app%2Fapp.module.ts,app%2Fapp.component.css if you go to eg. https://angular-router-basic-example-2ccpzg.stackblitz.io/form/1/2 you will see nested parent/child component. Try to trace your problem or provide minimum working example in your answer.